# Non-Flash Checkerboard Effect Slideshow or Image Swap

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, css-transitions

What would be the most efficient way to duplicate the Flash animation shown on this site's home page, without using Flash?   http://www.redhotdubai.com/ Must support IE7+ and all other major browsers.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you conducted? What have you learned in order to try this? What mark-up are you using?

Comment: As you can see by the tags I applied to the post, I'm considering jQuery, html5-canvas (with a polyfill for the older browsers) or css-transitions.  Am not asking for a free answer just wondering which of these directions I should pursue, or if there is one I haven't listed that I should consider.  Actual markup will be determined by which of the methods I start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a `canvas` element, since you'll need masking and there's a lot of animation going on.  Using CSS and the DOM would be too hacky in the end, a canvas solution would run faster and more reliably in the end.

Here's some documentation on the relevant canvas method you'll need:

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Slicing

Comment: Thanks, Luke.  I had previously overlooked slicing.  I'll give it a go.